# What are the lenses with FOV 90-100 degrees for 23mm diagonal sensor ? and their mount name?

Tags: lens

What are the lenses with a FOV 90-100 degrees (approximately) for 23mm diagonal sensor ?
Is there any norm name for this kind of sensor or any named mount, to which is associated image-circle and sensor-lense distance ?

More specifically, the sensor is:

```
diagonal 23.1mm (type 1.4)
8432x5680 Mpixels = 47.9 Mpixels
```

I'm looking for rather compact lenses, if possible telecentric, with good resolution (8.5k in this case), but not too sharp (rather creamy/soft, like Arri signature).

EDIT: To a mount is associated an image circle and a given distance lense-sensor, hence the mount is not so much about the mechanical part but important lense features. Hence, a "mount system" is coupled in several ways to a sensor.

Comment: "Best" is often a matter of opinion. It depends what your actual use-case is. You're starting from an odd set of requirements. Normally people start with a known camera, with a known mount & sensor size [sensors are not measured on the diagonal, but yours sounds like what would be called 1.5"] What precisely are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Please take the time to take the [Tour](https://photo.stackexchange.com/tour) and read the [Help pages](https://photo.stackexchange.com/help), especially [What topics can I ask about here?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: The mount is completely independent of the sensor. You can't expect anyone to know for which kind of mount you need a lens just by describing the sensor.

Comment: You mention *telecentric* which is commonly used in machine vision. These are expensive lenses (in the USD 1k-10k range) and fixed focus. Do you really want telecentric? C-mount is common for telecentric lenses.

Comment: @qrk I prefer telecentric, which is also present in photography and cinematography. c mount is indeed interesting, since there is a 22mm image circle, which could (depending on the lens) fit the 23mm sensor I'm considering. Micro 4/3 is also a good mount candidate, with the same image circle, but it's not obvious that the lenses are telecentric, since they try to yield compact and lightweight lenses.

Comment: @Soleil Check out [Edmund Scientific](https://www.edmundoptics.com/c/telecentric-lenses/1003/#) as they have a large line of telecentric lenses in a few mounts. These are designed for industrial use (machine vision) in metrology. Telecentric lenses are **not** classified by angular field of view which is why this question is confusing.

Comment: When you say you prefer telecentric lenses, are you referring to object-space telecentricity, or image-space telecentricity, or both (bi-telecentric)? Why?

Comment: Image telecentric: in order to minimize focus and out of focus chromatic aberrations on high density digital sensor, breathing and few other image qualities.

Comment: There is an abundance of contemporary cinema glass available for m4/3 mount. C mount not so much these days  because c Mount specifies only the physical interface and not a sensor/film size. Image circles vary significantly between lenses depending on anticipated application…and these days those are not high resolution video. Overall picking a sensor first seems like the dog’s tail. There are off the shelf systems for getting cinematic effect.

Comment: @BobMacaroniMcStevens Good point for the c mount. What do you mean by "There are off the shelf systems for getting cinematic effect" ?

Comment: There are cinema cameras with suitable sensors that accept readily available lenses that cost more than a nice new automobile. There are consumer, professional, and prosumer cameras that produce similar results and can be adapted to high end glass. If that's what you want, starting with a sensor is the tail wagging the dog.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this sensor has an aspect ratio of 3:2 (same as full frame 35mm sensor). If true, diagonal measure is 23mm, then the sensor height is 12.8mm and the sensor length is 19.2mm

Armed with these dimensions, I use conventional lens math to calculate what focal lengths will deliver an angle of view of 90° and 100°.

It’s the focal length combined with the sensor dimensions that dictate the resulting angles of view. It is industry standard to give the diagonal angle of view. This is because the diagonal measure of a rectangle is the longer of the three values which are height, length, and diagonal.

Since the diagonal is the longest of the three, the diagonal angle of view is the widest thus the one most often given. This might not make much sense but consider this industry standard is based on advertising puffing. Same for TV sets, their size is advertised based on their diagonal measurement.

That being said:

Mount a 11.5 mm lens and the angles of view will be – 58.2° vertical – 79.7° horizontal -- 90° diagonal

Mount a 9.7mm lens and the angles of view will be – 66.8° vertical – 89.4° horizontal -- 100° diagonal

It’s the focal length makes this happen, not the mount. Exception if the mount has an optical element that modifies the focal length of the mounted lens.

Formula: 35mm frame 24mm by 36mm with 50mm lens

Find diagonal = sq. root 24^2 + 36^2 = 43.27mm

Sove for angle of view
ATAN(43.27/2/50)*2

ATAN(0.4327) = 23.4 * 2 = 46.8°

ATAN is ArcTan a trig function

This formula derives the angle of view when the camera is working at infinity.

d = format dimension such as the diagonal
f = focal length

Angle of view = ATAN (d/2/f)2

An APS-C frame size is 16mm by 24mm diagonal = 28.8mm

Find angle of view if 30mm lens is mounted

ATAN(28.8/2/30)2

Angle of view = ATAN(0.48)2

Angle of view = 25.64 X 2 = 51.28°

Perhaps someone can post this formula better. I can't remember the text book of origin, been using it for more than 30 years.

Comment: Well, see my edit. I'm invoking mount not as a mechanical feature but as a system with given image circle and lensse-sensor distance.

Comment: Can you update your answer with formulas which yield angles ?

Comment: Can you provide full formulas and their origin, instead of using numbers (no need for Pythagore) ? The simplicity of your formulas (with numbers) involve several approximations that you did not mentioned, and this feels suspect. You might want to use a latex notation and rendering (https://quicklatex.com/) since there is no mathjax here.

Comment: Inside the camera a ray trace reveals a triangle The height is the focal length. The base is a one of the format dimensions. We know the dimensions of two sides of this triangle. We bisect to create a right triangle. The TAN of ½ the apex angle is opposite side divided by adjacent side. The ARTAN of this division is the angle in degrees. Twice this angle is apex of the image cone. The object cone (angle) is the same as the image angle.

Comment: I believe you need somewhere the distance between the lens and the sensor, therefore it still seems suspect. This distance is also associated to the mount, because lenses are built to have the focus range [minimum distance-infinity] adapted to this distance (except few multimount lenses).

Comment: When focused on infinity, the rear nodal distance to sensor is the published focal length. Since the lens has limited ability to refract (Latin "bend backwards") the back focus distance increase as we focus on nearby objects. Suppose a 50mm lens is imagining an object 1000mm away. We express the 50mm in diopters thus 1/50 X 1000 = 20d. The object distance also 1/1000 X 1000 = 1d. We invert this sign thus -1d. We add 20 + -1 = 19d. Now we covert this value to millimeters 1/19 X 1000 = 52.6mm. This is the revised working focal length for an object distance 1000mm distant.

Comment: The quantity *dioptre* is homogenous to $1/L$, which is $1m^{-1}$ where (m~meter) [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dioptre].  So nothing after "nearby object" makes sense. Also please try as much as possible to justify your reasoning and calculation insead of "poping" things out of a magic hat ("we invert this sign" ????, etc), this will help people to understand what your are writing.

Comment: I did the best I  could - why not just use published tables of angle of view? I am giving up!